# MLFlow model registry : Access Control for Model stage update - on-prem MLFlow

Tags: mlflow

I am trying to implement access control for who could update the model stage in on-prem MLFlow.

Can u help with pointers on how we can setup the access control /approval workflow for model stage upgrade in on-prem MLFlow implementation.

Thanks,
Deepak

I have the MLflow setup . Logged, registered the model to model registry. Now I want to setup access control for the model registry stage update to control who can update the stage.